# in java eclipse Memory Analyzer: Acquire Heap Dump Dialog shows no PID to acquire

Tags: java, eclipse

I downloaded the Memory Analyzer from Eclipse marketplace, restarted it, launched my application and clicked on "Acquire Heap Dump Dialog".

But the list of process remains empty in the Acquire Heap Dump Dialog window even after refreshing, choosing a heap dump provider in Configure or relaunching the app.

Why it does not show any PID to acquire??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you don't have a JDK installed.
A JRE doesn't have jps or jmap.
If MAT is correctly configured to point to a JDK you should at least see a jps instance in the list of processes.

Have a look at the error log (Window > Error Log) to see if there were problems.